# Displaying Application by tapping notification

Tags: android

I know that several similar questions have been asked but the answers all included deprecated solutions.

I have started to develop an application on android which displays some information on a notification (which stays always on) and I want the user to be able to go to the application by tapping on the notification.

Below is what I have done which is not working as nothing happens when I tap on the notification (which displays properly)

I have this method called SendNotification which is invoked by keypresses and does little besides call

```
private void DispatchNotification(String numValue,String nameValue){
        Intent intent=new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pIntent=PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder= new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
        builder.setAutoCancel(false);
        builder.setContentTitle("Just Title");
        builder.setContentText(nameValue+" "+numValue);
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.abc_popup_background_mtrl_mult);
        Notification notification = builder.build();
        notification.flags|= Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
        builder.addAction(R.drawable.abc_popup_background_mtrl_mult,"MENU",null);
        builder.setContentIntent(pIntent);
        NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager)this.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        manager.notify(8,notification);
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

As per the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification.html), this is how you can build a notification with an intent to open an Activity:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
    new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
    .setContentTitle("My notification")
    .setContentText("Hello World!");

Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, ResultActivity.class);

// Because clicking the notification opens a new ("special") activity, there's
// no need to create an artificial back stack.
PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
    PendingIntent.getActivity(
    this,
    0,
    resultIntent,
    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
);

mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
// Sets an ID for the notification
int mNotificationId = 001;
// Gets an instance of the NotificationManager service
NotificationManager mNotifyMgr = 
        (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
// Builds the notification and issues it.
mBuilder.setOngoing(true);
mNotifyMgr.notify(mNotificationId, mBuilder.build());
```

Comment: This is a generic solution for opening an activity. Is it similar when i want to open the same activity that created the notification?

Comment: You specify which activity to open as such: `Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, ResultActivity.class);` where `ResultActivity.class` is your activity of choice. @Kozos

Answer (score 1):

Step #1: Get rid of your existing `builder.build()` call.

Step #2: Replace `notification.flags|= Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;` with `builder.setOngoing(true);`.

Step #3: Replace `manager.notify(8,notification)` with `manager.notify(8, builder.build());`

IOW, you are building your `Notification` before you are done with the `Builder`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(ctx, MainActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK );
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(ctx, 0 /* Request code */, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT|PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(ctx)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon_notification)
            .setContentTitle("Your app name")
            .setContentText(message)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
```